# What is the difference between assigning to std::tie and tuple of references?

Tags: c++, reference, tuples

I am a bit puzzled by the following tuple business:

```
int testint = 1;
float testfloat = .1f;
std::tie( testint, testfloat ) = std::make_tuple( testint, testfloat );
std::tuple<int&, float&> test = std::make_tuple( testint, testfloat );
```

With `std::tie` it works, but assigning directly to the tuple of references doesn't compile, giving

> "error: conversion from ‘std::tuple<int, float>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::tuple<int&, float&>’ requested"

or

> "no suitable user-defined conversion from std::tuple<int, float> to std::tuple<int&, float&>"

Why? I double checked with the compiler if it's really the same type that is being assigned to by doing this:

```
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype( std::tie( testint, testfloat ) ), std::tuple<int&, float&>>::value, "??" );
```

Which evaluates as true.

I also checked [online](http://gcc.godbolt.org) to see if it maybe was the fault of msvc, but all compilers give the same result.

Comment: define "doesn't work" and please post complete code.

Comment: I replaced the "doesn't work", but I think the code is complete enough. What would be missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `std::tie()` function actually initializes the members of the `std::tuple<T&...>` of references where is the `std::tuple<T&...>` can't be initialized by a templatory `std::tuple<T...>`. The operation `std::tie()` does and initializing a corresponding object would be expressed like this:

```
std::tuple<int&, float&> test = 
    std::tuple<int&, float&>(testint, testfloat) = std::make_tuple(testint, testfloat);
```

(obviously, you would normally use different values than those of the already bound variables).

Comment: Ah I think I understand. the std::tie(a, b) is a tuple of two references to a and b, while the std::tuple<int&, float&> doesn't reference anything. Is that the point here?

Comment: @Barabas: yes, that is correct. I had contemplated different notations and eventually settled with the joined assignment/initialization mainly because the original was trying to do an initialization, too.

Answer (score 20):

Both `make_tuple` and `tie` will deduce the returned type by arguments. But `tie` will make a lvalue reference type according to deduced type and `make_tuple` will make an actual tuple.

```
std::tuple<int&, float&> a = std::tie( testint, testfloat );

std::tuple<int , float > b = std::make_tuple( testint, testfloat );
```

The goal of `tie` is making a temporary tuple to avoid temporary copies of tied objects, the bad effect is, you can not `return` a `tie` if entry objects are local temporary.

Comment: I understand that std::tie makes a tuple of lvalue references, but what's the difference with the std::tuple<int&, float&> on the next line?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the rhs `std::make_tuple(testint, testfloat)` doesn't return an array of references, it returns `std::tuple<int, int>`, which is a temporary whose values can't bind to lvalue-references. If you need a tuple of references, you can use the helper function [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
auto test = std::make_tuple(std::ref(a), std::ref(b));
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The difference between this and `tie` is that the references are initialized by `std::tie(a, b)` on construction.

Comment: Then what are the values in the std::tie tuple, if not lvalue references?
And the std::make_tuple producing a temporary is not the issue, the same behaviour can be observed when storing the result of std::make_pair in a local variable and then trying to assign it to a tuple of references or std::tie

Comment: @Barabas The values in the std::tie tuple *are* lvalue references. They are initialized by `a` and `b` respectively.

Answer (score -1):

I guess, because they are different types and there is no conversion from one to another, but there is a templated copy assignment operator, that works in case of a tie.

Checking the code

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::tuple<int> a{};

    std::cout << std::get<0>(a) << std::endl;

    std::tuple<float> b{1.f}; //note float type

    a = b;

    std::cout << std::get<0>(a) << std::endl;

}
output: 0 1
```

suggests, that it's probably correct.