# Initialize tuple of references with reference to tuple

Tags: c++, reference, tuples

If I have the code

```
#include <tuple>

using Vec3 = std::tuple<float, float, float>;
using Vec3Ref = std::tuple<float&, float&, float&>;

void stuff ()
{
  Vec3 foo (0,0,0);
  Vec3Ref bar (foo);
}
```

I get the error

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:100:4: error: binding of reference to type 'float' to
a value of type 'const float' drops qualifiers

: _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }

^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

//snip...

/usr/include/c++/4.6/tuple:257:11: note: in instantiation of function template
specialization 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, float &, float &, float &>::_Tuple_impl
<float, float, float>' requested here

: _Inherited(static_cast<const _Tuple_impl<0, _UElements...>&>(__in))

^

18 : note: in instantiation of function template specialization
'std::tuple::tuple' requested here

Vec3Ref bar (foo);

^
```

The closest thing I've found is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800303/what-is-the-difference-between-assigning-to-stdtie-and-tuple-of-references), but the problem there seems to be about initializing with a tuple returned from `std::make_tuple`, which is an rvalue. `foo`, however, is very much an lvalue. Why does this not work? How is this different from using `std::tie`?

Comment: What's wrong with Vec3& (as Vec3Ref) ?

Comment: @DieterLücking Assignable swizzles. You can't make a reference to the outside structure if it doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Clang 3.0.6.

Comment: @dyp In light of this, I can't see how assigning to `std::tie` works at all; the `operator=` has the same overloads as the constructor.

Comment: This problem is not symmetric, it does not appear for rvalues and it does not appear when testing `is_convertible<float&, float>` (i.e. when the argument has the references and the constructed object doesn't).

Comment: @Dan Assigning does not follow the same rules as binding to/initializing a reference. You can assign an rvalue to an lvalue reference, but you cannot initialize an lvalue reference with an rvalue (of the same type).

Answer (score 2):

Github draft from 2014-07-23, [tuple.cnstr]

> ```
> template <class... UType> constexpr tuple(tuple<UTypes...>&& u);
> ```
>
> <sup>18</sup> *Requires:* `sizeof...(Types) == sizeof...(UTypes)`.
>   `is_constructible<Ti, Ui&&>::value` is `true` for all *i*.
>
> <sup>20</sup> *Remark:* This constructor shall not participate in
>   overload resolution unless each type in `UTypes` is implicitly
>   convertible to its corresponding type in `Types`.

The *Remarks:* section defines the SFINAE. Note how it's different from the *Requires:* section by requiring the use of `is_convertible` instead of `is_constructible`.

In the OP's example, this leads to the check `is_convertible<float, float&>`, which is false: a `float` xvalue cannot be bound to a `float` lvalue reference:

`is_convertible` [meta.rel]/4

> Given the following function prototype:
>
> ```
> template <class T>
> add_rvalue_reference_t<T>::type create() noexcept;
> ```
>
> the predicate condition for a template specialization `is_convertible<From, To>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following vode would be well-formed, including any implicit conversions to the return type of the function:
>
> ```
> To test() {
>     return create<From>();
> }
> ```

Here,

```
float& test() {
    return create<float>();
}
```

is ill-formed, `create<float>()` returns a `float&&`, that is, an xvalue. The result cannot be bound to an lvalue-reference.

---

It is well-known that the construction of `tuple` is not perfect; see for example [proposal N3680](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3680.html), which also addresses [LWG defect 2051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2051).

None of those seem to address the issue in the OP, however.

Comment: To make this work, one had to include the value category of the tuple argument and merge this with the reference qualifiers of the tuple element's type. The problem should also occur for `tuple<Derived>` -> `tuple<Base&>`.