# C++ std::tuple<Ts&&...> <-> std::tuple<Ts...>&& conversion

Tags: c++, c++20, c++23

In gcc 12.1.0, currently the commented lines don't compile.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::tuple<int, std::string, float> tup {1, "aaa", 3.0f};

    // ERROR
    // std::tuple<int&, std::string&, float&> tup_ref (tup);

    // OK...
    std::tuple<int&, std::string&, float&> tup_ref (std::get<0>(tup), std::get<1>(tup), std::get<2>(tup));

    // ERROR
    // std::tuple<int&, const std::string&, float&> tup_ref2 (tup);

    // OK
    std::tuple<int&, const std::string&, float&> tup_ref2 (std::get<0>(tup), std::get<1>(tup), std::get<2>(tup));

    // ERROR
    // const std::tuple<int&, std::string&, float&> const_tup_ref (tup_ref2);

    // OK
    [[maybe_unused]] const std::tuple<int&, const std::string&, float&>& const_tup_ref (tup_ref2);

    // ERROR.. why? this is const reference, you can't mutate 1th std::string anyway
    // const std::tuple<int&, std::string&, float&>& const_tup_ref3 (tup_ref2);

    // OK
    [[maybe_unused]] const std::tuple<const int&, const std::string&, const float&>& const_tup_ref2 (tup_ref2);

}
```

Demo: [Link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ywup3wLW41XnCpjE)

I see no valid reason that C++ should ban these conversions ("they are not supported yet" is understandable), are there plans in later C++ standard to support these cases?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918426/initialize-tuple-of-references-with-reference-to-tuple

Comment: _"why? this is const reference, you can't mutate 1th std::string anyway"_ - If it would compile, the `tuple` would have a non-`const` ref to the `string`. That you made the `tuple` itself `const` doesn't matter. You can't "mend" the `const` drop after the fact.

Comment: @apetrai uncomment commented lines