# What is the difference between std::tie and std::make_tuple with std::ref arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, tuples

Is there any semantic difference between writing the expression

```
std::tie( x, y, z )
```

and the following expression?

```
std::make_tuple( std::ref(x), std::ref(y), std::ref(z) )
```

If so, what are the differences?

By the way, this question is not asking the same as [What is the difference between assigning to `std::tie` and tuple of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800303/what-is-the-difference-between-assigning-to-stdtie-and-tuple-of-references) because the tuple of references is not created via `std::ref`, but by explicitly specifying the type.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is almost<sup>†</sup> no functional difference between the two expressions. `tie()` is just shorter whereas `make_tuple()` is more generic.

---

According to [tuple.creation], [`make_tuple`](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.creation#2) does:

> ```
> template<class... Types>
> constexpr tuple<VTypes...> make_tuple(Types&&... t);
> ```
>
> Let `Ui` be `decay_t<Ti>` for each `Ti` in Types. Then each `Vi` in `VTypes` is `X&` if `Ui` equals `reference_wrapper<X>`, otherwise `Vi` is `Ui`.

Hence `std::make_tuple( std::ref(x), std::ref(y), std::ref(z) )` yields<sup>†</sup> a `std::tuple<X&, Y&, Z&>`.

On the other hand, [`tie`](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple.creation#7) does:

> ```
> template<class... Types>
> constexpr tuple<Types&...> tie(Types&... t) noexcept;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* `tuple<Types&...>(t...)`. When an argument in `t` is `ignore`, assigning any value to the corresponding tuple element has no effect.

Hence, `std::tie(x, y, z)` also yields a `std::tuple<X&, Y&, Z&>`.

---

<sup>†</sup>Except in one [edge case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36841729/2069064).

Answer (score 16):

There is a difference when any of `x`, `y` and `z` is a specialization of `std::reference_wrapper`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

void f(std::reference_wrapper<int> x, int y, int z)
{
    std::tie(x,y,z); // type is std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int>&, int&, int&>
    std::make_tuple(std::ref(x),std::ref(y),std::ref(z)); // type is std::tuple<int&, int&, int&>
}
```